# Highcharts: Zebra color chart background

Tags: highcharts

How do I set highchart background as zebra style like below?
Color doesn't relate with data.
It is just zebra style on vertical grid of x axis.
PS. sorry about figure. I don't permission to insert image.
Thank you

- |**color1**|color2|**color1**|color2|
- |**color1**|color2|**color1**|color2|
- |**color1**|color2|**color1**|color2|
- |**color1**|color2|**color1**|color2|  ...
- 0-----10------20------30------40

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the `plotBackgroundColor` from the `chart` option combined with the `alternateGridColor` from the `xAxis` options.

Here is an example :

```
var color1 = 'rgba( 255, 0, 0, .3 )';
var color2 = 'rgba(255, 0, 255, .2)';

chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: color1
},
xAxis: {
    alternateGridColor: color2,
    ...
},
...
```

A live example : http://jsfiddle.net/YRgBf/1/

Comment: It is mix of 2 colors and 
have to do trial and error to find formula to get right final colors.
Does it have straightforward way?

Comment: @user2575561 What do you mean by "have to do trial and error to find formula to get right final colors" ? You have some javascript code before to calculate colors ? If you have some code, can you give us a jsFiddle with it ?

Comment: Sorry. My bad. Just set alpha as 1 and result is what I want.