# D3JS - Horizontal highlight on scatter plot

Tags: d3.js, highlight

I have a D3JS scatter plot, with circles, and a white background.

I want to add 2 horizontal rectangles, all over the graph on X-axis, BEHIND the circles, and between certain values on Y axis.

The 2 grey areas I need are the following (made w/ Photoshop) : [image: Horizontal highligths]

The first rectangle is between 10 and 20 on X axis, and the second one is between 30 and 35.

I found this thread : [How to add a highlight mark/area to a chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235469/how-to-add-a-highlight-mark-area-to-a-chart)
But I don't know how to adapt it for my horizontal example as it is not as simple as a rotation of this vertical solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably achieve the same effect by creating two SVG rectangles with some opacity.  Of course you'd want to fill in the correct data or generate it from your scales.

```
 var rectOne = svg.append("rect")
                  .attr("x", 10)
                  .attr("y", 10)
                  .attr("width", 50)
                  .attr("height", 100)
                  .style("fill-opacity", 0.5)
                  .style("fill", "grey")

 var rectTwo = svg.append("rect")
                  .attr("x", 10)
                  .attr("y", 10)
                  .attr("width", 50)
                  .attr("height", 100)
                  .style("fill-opacity", 0.5)
                  .style("fill", "grey")
```